# How to reduce celeryd memory consumption?

Tags: ubuntu, python, django

I'm using celery 2.5.1 with django on a micro ec2 instance with 613mb memory and as such have to keep memory consumption down.

Currently I'm using it only for the scheduler "celery beat" as a web interface to cron, though I hope to use it for more in the future.  I've noticed it is the biggest consumer of memory on my micro machine even though I have configured the number of workers to one.  I don't have many other options set in settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_BACKEND = 'djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'database'

BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 2
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 20
CELERYD_SOFT_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 5 * 60
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 6 * 60
```

Here's the details via top:

```
 PID USER  NI CPU%  VIRT   SHR  RES  MEM% Command 
1065 wuser 10  0.0  283M  4548  85m  14.3 python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat
1025 wuser 10  1.0  577M  6368  67m  11.2 python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat
1071 wuser 10  0.0  578M  2384  62m  10.6 python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat
```

That's about 214mb of memory (and not much shared) to run a cron job occasionally.  Have I done anything wrong, or can this be reduced about ten-fold somehow?  ;)

**Update**: here's my upstart config:

```
description "Celery Daemon"

start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems)
stop on runlevel [016]
nice 10
respawn
respawn limit 5 10
chdir /home/wuser/wuser/
env CELERYD_OPTS=--concurrency=1

exec sudo -u wuser -H /usr/bin/python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat --concurrency=1 --loglevel info --logfile /var/tmp/celeryd.log
```

**Update 2**:

I notice there is one root process, one user child process, and two grandchildren from that.  So I think it isn't a matter of duplicate startup.

```
root  34580  1556 sudo -u wuser -H /usr/bin/python manage_prod.py celeryd 
wuser  577M 67548 └─ python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat --concurrency=1 
wuser  578M 63784    ├─  python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat --concurrency=1
wuser  271M 76260    └─  python manage_prod.py celeryd --beat --concurrency=1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make sure that celery is only including the bare minimum of your code (I've seen celery configured to import people's entire web applications... not pretty).  However, at the end of the day, you're looking at a very large chunk of Python, which is going to chew up a lot of memory by it's very nature.

If you want a low-memory task scheduling tool, I'd suggest real, honest-to-goodness cron.

Comment: +1 to this; celery may have started out as a scheduler, but its real strengths are in its worker model.  Like @womble said, either stick to cron--or pick something that's specifically used for scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, you've given me some insight in to the problem.  Unfortunately to do its tasks it needs to import a lot of the code, though I wouldn't expect it to be so large.  In any case cron might not help much in absolute memory usage as it would have to run the same tasks ... however, (a big however) the cron job would release its memory when the task completed instead of sitting there in ram 98% of the time doing nothing.  Maybe the "recycle" options can help.

Comment: Celery itself is a large quantity of code; removing that from the jobs you need to run would save you a fair amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague shared a trick a couple of years after I asked this question.

Basically you factor your application task into a separate script, and have celery run it via a subprocess.  That way it can reclaim all the application memory regularly like cron would.

Sorry haven't mentioned it until now, the site just reminded me the question exists.  ;-)